# Life cycle of view android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-lifecycle

I want some view animation to occur after resuming my activity, but I can't succeed to catch the time after all the views loaded and the animation started before all the views loaded (before the animation transition).
i tried to use onDraw, onWindowFocusChange, onResume, I discovered that onDraw is the last method on the life cycle of view but I still saw that the animation start before the user see the all the views

Comment: post some code of your `onCreate()` and when you start the animation.

Comment: I start the animation on onDraw method

Answer (score 4):

Here is Android Activity lifecycle & Android View lifecycle tested on my device (Sony Z1 Compact)

```
Start an Activity
    Activity: onCreate
    Activity: onStart
    Activity: onResume
    View: onAttachedToWindow
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    Activity: onPause
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    # Start to another Activity
    # Back from another Activity
    Activity: onResume
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    Activity: onPause
    Activity: onStop
    Activity: onDestroy
    View: onDetachedFromWindow

Turn Off Screen
    Activity: onCreate
    Activity: onStart
    Activity: onResume
    View: onAttachedToWindow
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    Activity: onPause
    Activity: onStop
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    # Turn Off Screen
    # Turn On Screen
    Activity: onStart
    Activity: onResume
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    Activity: onPause
    Activity: onStop
    Activity: onDestroy
    View: onDetachedFromWindow

Switch Application
    Activity: onCreate
    Activity: onStart
    Activity: onResume
    View: onAttachedToWindow
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    Activity: onPause
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    Activity: onStop
    # Switch to Application
    # Back from Application
    Activity: onStart
    Activity: onResume
    View: onWindowFocusChanged true
    # Running
    Activity: onPause
    View: onWindowFocusChanged false
    Activity: onStop
    Activity: onDestroy
    View: onDetachedFromWindow
```

Comment: This is very helpful, because it shows the View's actual lifecycle, not just the first half like most documentation I've found.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead of a view as fragments unless views have a life cycle. The life cycle is bound to their Activity where they are embedded.

See also: [What is the benefit of using Fragments in Android, rather than Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617696/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-fragments-in-android-rather-than-views)

**Edit:**

Try starting your animation delayed:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Start your animation here.
    }
});
```

Comment: My view is already in a fragment, this is not relevant to my question at all.

Comment: So why don't you then forward the Fragment lifecycle calls to your view?

Comment: because I see the animation after it started when I put my animation on onDraw() nethod

Comment: In my implement I do it but the problem still occur

Comment: I guess without posting your code, nobody can assist you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a splash activity. In this splash activity you can show your animation.

[How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

also if you need to calculate sth while it shows animation, use a thread to calculate and send it to your main activity

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: This has nothing to do with splash activity or with passing data between activities, I have an animation that I want to start the moment that the activity is visible to the user and the views are rendered. where ever I tried so far to put the start of the animation was too soon